# Trigger doesnt want to work. However it does work well when in style

Tags: wpf, xaml, triggers

```
<Button Name="btnNewGame" Margin="120,292,450,180" Style="{StaticResource mainLobbyBtnStyle}">
        <Grid Height="35" Width="200">
            ...
            <Line Name="lineNewGame" X1="200" X2="200" Y1="0" Y2="35" ... />
        </Grid>
        <Button.Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Content" Value="qwerty"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Button.Triggers>
</Button>
```

I get "'*IsMouseOver*' member is not valid because it does not have a qualifying type name". Need help in fixing this.

And second question.
Can i change parameters of *lineNewGame* in my button trigger? How?

Comment: So event trigger. Can i change parameters of lineNewGame in my button event trigger?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@NDQuattro, why would that suck? By adding 2 more lines to your code I got it working for me....

```
 <Button Name="btnNewGame" Margin="120,292,450,180">
     <Grid Height="35" Width="200">
         <Line Name="lineNewGame" X1="200" X2="200" Y1="0" Y2="35" ... />
     </Grid>
     <Button.Style>
         <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}"
                BasedOn="{StaticResource mainLobbyBtnStyle}">
           <Style.Triggers> 
              <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                  <Setter Property="Content" Value="qwerty"/>
              </Trigger>
           </Style.Triggers> 
         </Style> 
     </Button.Style>
  </Button>
```

Answer (score 3):

To answer your first question:

You could use `UIElement.IsMouseOver` and `Button.Content` to avoid this error message. But then you would have the next problem: "Triggers collection members must be of type EventTrigger".

In `FrameworkElement` you can use:

```
EventTrigger
```

In `Style`, `ControlTemplate`, `DataTemplate` you can use:

```
EventTrigger,
Trigger or MultiTrigger,
DataTrigger or MultiDataTrigger
```

Answer (score 3):

Regular Triggers as well as DataTriggers are meant to be in a Style, period.

The only kind of trigger you can use directly as you're doing in your example, is EventTrigger, you then need to define an animation (in a storyboard) that will run when an event fires.

You can do it straight in though:

```
<Button>
   <Button.Style>
      <Style Target="Button">
         <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Content" Value="qwerty"/>
            </Trigger>
         </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
   </Button.Style>
</Button>
```